# Write down exception reason in a IIS 7 server

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I'm developing a WCF RESTful service with C# and .NET Framework 4.0.

All of my methods are like this one:

```
public List<User> GetAllUsers()
{
    List<User> usersList = null;
    OutgoingWebResponseContext ctx =
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse;

    try
    {
        using (var context = new AdnLineContext())
        {
            context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            if ((context.Users != null) &&
                (context.Users.Count() > 0))
            {
                usersList = context.Users.ToList();

                ctx.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
            }
            else
            {
                // No users found.
                ctx.SetStatusAsNotFound();
                ctx.SuppressEntityBody = true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        ctx.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        ctx.SuppressEntityBody = true;
    }

    return usersList;
}
```

As you can see, there is a `catch` block to handle unhandled exceptions and send HTTP Status code 500 as a response.

I have add this to `web.config` to trace those exceptions:

```
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="UserTraceSource" switchValue="Error, Information, Warning, ActivityTracing" >
    <listeners>
      <add name="xml"
         type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
         initializeData="D:\logs\MyTraces.svclog" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
<trace autoflush="true" />
</system.diagnostics>
```

But I don't see anything when an exception occurs.

**What do I have to add to each catch block to write down ex.Message into a trace log?**

This is my `web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MyProjectWCFService.MyProjectService"
               behaviorConfiguration="MyProjectServiceBehaviour">
        <endpoint address=""
                  contract="MyProjectWCFService.IMyProjectService"
                  behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehavior"
                  binding="webHttpBinding" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restfulBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyProjectServiceBehaviour">

          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />

          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyProjectContext"
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
          connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyProject;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="UserTraceSource" switchValue="Error, Information, Warning, ActivityTracing" >
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml"
             type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
             initializeData="D:\log\MyProjectTraces.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was on web.config. I haven't defined a trace.

This is how I have solved the problem:

```
<system.diagnostics>
<trace autoflush="true" >
  <listeners>
    <add name="myListener"
       type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
       initializeData="D:\log\MyProjectTraces.svclog" />
    <remove name="Default"/>
  </listeners>
</trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

And I have also used James' answer:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ctx.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    ctx.SuppressEntityBody = true;
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message, "GetAllUsers"); // log exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.Trace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to notify the listeners that something needs to be logged e.g.

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ctx.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    ctx.SuppressEntityBody = true;
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message, "GetAllUsers"); // log exception
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have published my project on IIS 7 with your code and I don't get anything on `MyTraces.svclog`.

Comment: @VansFannel actually looking at your configuration you don't have any actual `TRACE` level listeners - for example, if you call `throw;` at the end of the catch block does your exception get logged?

Comment: I have added the `throw;` statement and I don't get the exception logged.

Comment: I have added my `web.config`to my question.

Comment: @VansFannel hmm should be working, does your web app have permissions to write to that directory? Try giving it full permissions to test.

Comment: there was an error on web.config. There wasn't defined a trace. Look at my answer. Thanks a lot.